# Maven Archetype: How to add more than one archetype in same maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have a maven plugin to setup a custom archetype, whose code can be found [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-maven-plugin) on github.

Now, I need to add another archetype whose pom file has an extra dependency. Other than that, only a few resource files differ. I need to re-use the tasks defined for the existing archetype.

Do I need to create a different plugin to create this archetype? How can i have multiple archetypes under same group?

P.S. I'm new to Maven world.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I could do it:

Multiple archetypes can be created under same group, for a particular maven plugin. A maven archetype template can be created with

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-mvn-archetypes).

Comment: In other words, a multi-module archetype can be used to generate multiple projects